# How to pass the values from post response to get request in Karate using read

Tags: karate

In my post request I am getting something like this,

{
"id": 139,
"name": "Test"
}

Now i want to pass this id within my Get request but by calling the get feature file using read

I can pass this id in Get request within same scenario without calling other feature file but not sure how to pass this id in other feature file

I have saved the response in separate variable, NewlyCreatedId and tried to pass it with get request

- def NewlyCreatedId = response.id
- def mygetFeatureFile = call read('get.feature') { id: NewlyCreatedId }

But this is not working

Comment: This should work                                                                                                                          * def mygetFeatureFile = call read('get-file.feature') { id: '#(NewlyCreatedId)' }

Comment: Thank you so much Shreyansh, it's working fine now.